# Change form action according to select option

Tags: forms, html-select

I have a simple form:

```
<form name="simple" id="simple" method="post" action="X.php">
<select name="select">
<option value="none"> Select </option>
<option value="1">1st</option>
<option value="2">2nd</option>
<option value="3">3rd</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I want X (X.php) to change with option values. 
For example, when user selects 1st, it should change to 1.php.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, example with jquery is as follows:

```
$("#selectID").change(function() {
  var action = $(this).val();
  $("#simple").attr("action", action + ".php"); // Can also use .prop("action", action + ".php"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Works great (y)